# How to make the ViewPager's items to be destroyed on orientation changes?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-orientation

I have a ViewPager that I shows more than one item. I used the solution of putting multiple items in one fragment and I created an Adapter that calculates how many items I can put per fragment based in the width of the screen.

The getItem of my FragmentPagerAdapter creates a range of items for each fragment, dividing the quantity of items for each fragment.

For example, I have 12 items and in the portrait orientation, I can put 3 items. The getItem will create fragments with the range of 0-2, 3-5, 6-8 and 9-11. In the landscape orientation, since the width of the screen is bigger, I can put, for example, 5 items. So, the ranges would be 0-4, 5-8 and 9-11.

With this requirement, I need to create new Fragments and destroy the old ones on orientation changes.

I created a solution, but it depends on the method isChangingConfigurations() of the Activity. But this method just exists for API level 11 and above. So I can't use it.

Basically, I I'm not allowing the Fragment to save its state and I'm removing it in the onPause if the configuration is changing. But since I don't have this method in old android versions, I need another solution.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to put one item in each fragment, then use your calculations to determine how many fragments to show at one time? See http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

Comment: @CommonsWare, I've seen this solution before and I've used it in another situation. But now, I need the user to be able to click on the items. With your approach, the other items doesn't receive touch events.

Comment: "the other items doesn't receive touch events" -- yes, they do. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/MultiView1

Comment: Hum... I'll give it a try.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I've tried your solution and I've used views instead of fragments. I calculated how many pages I could show based on the screen's width and returned 1.0f/quantityOfPages in the getPageWidth. It was working well until I've seen a ViewPager with less items than the limit. When I scroll that ViewPager, I see a very strange visual effect.

Comment: To solve this problem, I tested if the limit is less than the quantity of items.

Comment: @CommonsWare, your solution worked. But my boss want the ViewPager to show many items per page because the way the scrolling is done. He wants to be able to scroll many items with just a simple swipe. Anyway, in another situation, I'll try your solution again. Thank you!

Comment: "He wants to be able to scroll many items with just a simple swipe" -- which my solution already handles. If you swipe across the full width of the screen, where the `ViewPager` shows N pages, you will advance by N pages.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But he doesn't want to swipe across the full width of the screen. With the other approach, you just need to swipe a little bit to see the next N items. Well, I think your approach is better and easier to implement, with less chances of having bugs. But for this situation, he wants the other approach. Thank you anyway. I've bookmarked your approach.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (pagerAdapter != null) {
        pagerAdapter.removeAllfragments();
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And the code for adapter:

```
public void removeAllfragments()
{
    if ( mFragmentList != null ) {
        for ( Fragment fragment : mFragmentList ) {
            mFm.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
        }
        mFragmentList.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

mFragmentList should add fragments inside of:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to your current approach is probably to ensure that `getItem(int)` returns different values for the landscape and portrait orientations. The id is used to generate the fragment tag, that, after an orientation change, is used to retrieve a detached fragment and reattach it. With different ids for the situation where respectively 3 items and 5 items are next to each other, a fragment with 3 items will never be reattached if there should be 5.

By default, `getItemId(int)` simply returns the supplied position of the element, like so:

```
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

In order to return different ids for your situations, you have various options. A straightforward one would be to do something smart with the indices of all items displayed for the given position. Alternatively, you could do a simple device orientation check and offset the id with the total number of items, or do something smart with a string and a hashcode etc. Just make sure you return the same id for the same fragment in the same orientation.

Comment: This solution is almost complete, but it has a problem: the Fragment stopped being attached to the ViewPager, but it keeps being recreated with orientation changes and it keeps creating it's view, even that it's not visible. After a screen rotation, I have the fragments for the current orientation and the old fragment invisible. And the old fragments are never being destroyed. So, if I change the data for a smaller list of items, the last fragment tries to get a range of items that doesn't exist anymore, giving me an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Do you know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm testing if the Fragment has a possible range before updating its View, now. It avoids the IndexOutOfBoundsException. But the old fragments are still there, consuming memory and CPU to create a View that is not used anymore. If you have a solution for this, please let me know. One more thing: the destroyItem() is no called on configuration changes.